# I'm getting back into PHP however the below syntax is escaping me

Tags: php, slim

So I've been forced back into a PHP program...it is SLIM 4 based.

```
<?php

(require __DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php')->run();
```

I'm unsure of the `(require)` syntax above...look slike short for a function....but..not sure.

Comment: well its instantiating a class the source for which exists in that file, into an object and running the `run()` method. A bit of an ugly way of doing it

Comment: Method `run` is executed on some object, that was returned from `bootstrap.php`.

Comment: I guess looking at the content of `__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php'` will enlighten everything for you.

Comment: In this example, the bootstrap.php file returns a Slim App instance, then it invokes the run method of that app instance. It's much shorter because it requires no extra variable and this front controller file does only this single task.

Answer (score 0):

[require()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) is an `include()` that fails if the file cannot be included.

If the included PHP file ends with a `return` statement, it will return this value to the caller.

In your case, it looks like `bootstrap.php` returns an object with a `run()` method.

Note that `require()` is not actually a function but a language construct, so the parentheses are optional; these 2 lines are therefore equivalent:

```php
require('script.php');
```

```php
require 'script.php';
```

Comment: yea but the parenthese are outside of the require not after it..

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant that you can *also* add parentheses after `require` as I wanted to clarify that it's not really a function but a language construct. In your example, the parentheses around the whole expression are required so that PHP can understand that the `run()` method should be called on the object returned by the `require` call, not on the `'script.php'` string. Here is what happens if you omit the parentheses: https://3v4l.org/kdbM2